# EC2 rake instance on AWS ElasticBeanstalk Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rake, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a rails app running in an AWS EB container connected to an RDS postgres database, and we have some fairly intensive rake batch processes we would like to be able run on a dedicated EC2 instance connected to the same database.

My questions are:
- how would we create and launch these rake-specific instances, and then destroy them after the processes have run?
- how can you get at the terminal output to debug any issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the Rake Batch processes you need to do several things.

1. Setup AWS SDK with necessary role permissions to access AWS SQS (Simple Queue Service).
2. Put an item to the SQS when needed for batch processing.
3. Create a EC2 instance with necessary environments setup to run the rake processes to monitor the Queue and execute when items are present.

Optional: If you can write the code for rake tasks in Node.js or Java8, you can use AWS Lambda, where you don't need to keep a dedicated EC2 instance for batch jobs which is a less costly solution.